# NSTimer - integer multiplying

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Ok so recently I made a project which had like a bit of a gravity timer,

```
int speed = 5;
  NSTimer *gravitytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(gravity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)gravity {

image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x, image.center.y - speed)
}
```

The problem is that the speed keeps multiplying or keeps adding and the image goes faster and faster. I don't know what the problem is. I am a newbie so sorry if this is a bad question. Thanks to all the people who take the time to answer.

Comment: the integer is in the header file, that was just to show you.

Comment: The code you show won't make the image go faster and faster. Try putting in a longer time interval, and see if you still think it's speeding up.

Comment: learn how to use debugger and breakpoints. you may scheduled multiple timers.

Comment: Thanks I will check my code again, and tell you guys. Im going to post another question soon, ill send here when 90 minute restriction is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a timer, while it will *try* to call it every 0.01 seconds, you actually have no assurances that it will be called precisely at that rate (i.e. if it takes too long, it may skip one or two; if the main thread is blocked doing something else (and it's quite busy when the app first starts), you may skip quite a few). You can request to update `image.center` 100 times per second, but you have no guarantee that this is how often it actually will end up getting called.

If you wanted to use this technique to animate, you do so in a manner that isolates the speed of the animation from the frequency of the timer's selector is actually called. So, you might capture the start time, e.g.

```
CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CGPoint startPoint = image.center;
```

And then in your timer routine, you'd capture the elapsed time, multiply your speed times the elapsed time, and go from there:

```
-(void)gravity {
    CFAbsoluteTime elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.start;
    CGFloat speed  = 100.0;      // e.g. 100 points per second
    CGPoint center = startPoint;
    center.y += (elapsed * speed);
    image.center = center;
}
```

---

As an aside, I assume this is just an exercise in timers. If this were a real animation, there are far more effective ways to do such animation (e.g. block-based `animateWithDuration`, UIKit Dynamics, and if you really wanted to do something timer-based, you'd often use `CADisplayLink` rather than a `NSTimer`). Also, BTW, the frame rate of the display is 60fps, so there's no point in trying to call it more frequently than that.

Comment: Thanks~! Not only did it help I learnt something new. :) Sorry Im 13.